# How to unit test a method with no side effect?

Tags: unit-testing, testing

Is it possible to unit test a method like the following?

```
void AddNumbers() {
 int i = 2+2;
}
```

In other words, a method with no side effects really. Or are methods like these skipped and not usually tested? I would assume that "i" would normally be made a class-level variable, but then this has its drawbacks (nothing very big though).

Thanks

Comment: Your sample function has no effect, so the only thing you need to test is whether calling it throws an exception.  If the function has no return value and has no side-effect, then it has no effect at all (except to consume resources)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no value to a method with neither side-effects nor primary effects, such as you've presented.  Calling it - from test code or production code - would, well, have no effect.  So there's nothing to test, and no reason for the method.

Answer (score 1):

Mmm... this method has no side effect, but it is effectively doing nothing. A method without side effects, IMO, would be one that returns a value without changing any state (class or application), and this is how it can be tested again expected results. For any implementation, the method you wrote is invisible.